# Get Current Google Script Name to a Variable

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Does anyone know a way to get the name of the current google script file that's bound to the sheet you are using and write it to a variable? I want to put it into a sheets cell to keep track of changes I make.

Cheers

Comment: Please clarify what kind of script file are you interested on a stand-alone, bounded or both and add a brief description of your search/research efforts. Ref. [ask].

Comment: Its a script file within a sheets document. Its shared to various people so I want a way of updating the script code without continually making new sheets but at the same time keeping track of the script name. I've looked through a lot of the script reference on the google developers site but didn't find anything

Comment: Please [edit] you question to add the relevant details to it.

Answer (score 12):

```
var id = ScriptApp.getScriptId();
var name = DriveApp.getFileById(id).getName();
Logger.log(name);
```

Answer (score 1):

For standalone Google Scripts (not bound to any Google Sheet or Docs), you can use the DriveApp service to get the file name from Drive.

Right-click the file in Google Drive and copy the Share Link. Then get the ID from the shared link and use the DriveApp service to retrieve the name from the file ID.

```
function getName() {
 var fileId = "123";
 var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
 return file.getName();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Amit. Unfortunately the script is bound to a sheet so that won't work for me

Answer (score 0):

I know this is coming way after... but I faced the same roadblock recently (quite new to GAS).

Did you add the Drive app in Services? That's how I solved it: all Drive functions are available then.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).